# How to redirect user to login page when session token expired?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have Marionette + Node application.
When token expires the app does not react and user is not redirects to the LogIn page.
My question is - how to listen for session token status from Node?

Comment: Some example of your work would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day to you sir. Let me give you a quick intro to request handlers, endpoints, and middleware.

Express.js is very common request handler. Request handlers, do what they sound like they do. They handle requests; more specifically http requests. You can find plenty of examples online on how to create basic endpoints with express.js.

Now on to the more important part, middleware. In express at least middleware is software that's inserted between the arriving request, and the end point it was meant to reach.

I will use Express syntax.

Say I have an endpoint foo:

```
    Router.get('/foo', function(req, res) {});
```

However this endpoint should only be accessible under certain conditions. So I insert a middleware right in that request handler definition:

```
    Router.get('/foo', function iAmAMiddleware(req, res, next) {
      Here you can implement any logic you want. you have access to 
      the request, and the response. Meaning that if something in wrong
      in the request, then you can return a response from here like 

      res.send(404);


      BUT if all checks out all you have to do is call next() and 
      the flow will continue into the actual handler function. 
    },
    function iAmTheEndpointHandler(req, res) {})
```

Usage of middleware is huge. Google express middleware and you'll find plenty of information.

Good luck to you.